# Elasticsearch: must + exists query

Tags: elasticsearch

```
query = {
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[{
               "term": {
                  "company_id":"company_id_1234"
               },
               "exists": {
                  "field": "location_id"
               }
         }],
      }
   }
}

server.count(
    body=query,
    index="index_v1.2.0"
)
```

If I run the above code using the elasticsearch python client, I get `RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Failed to parse')` . However, if I comment out the part for the exists clause, the query runs without any trouble... How should I fix this so that I get the number of documents such that `company id = company_id_1234` and that have a `location_id` field? (editado)

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to be written like this, you're just missing some curly braces:

```
query = {
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
           {
               "term": {
                  "company_id":"company_id_1234"
               }
           },
           {
               "exists": {
                  "field": "location_id"
               }
           }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If I use yours, I get zero documents matching the query... However, I managed to run using the exists clause in a filter query, and I got 88K matches.

Comment: My query does nothing different than yours, it's just fixing the syntax issues yours had and resulting in a parsing_exception. With the information you provided, there's no way to know how to build the right query, because you haven't told anything about the index mapping and what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that to get some matches, I had to use a filter query instead.

```
query = {
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[{
               "term": {
                  "company_id":"company_id_1234"
               }
         }],
         "filter":{
            "exists": {
               "field": "location_id"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: There's no difference between must and filter when using term and exists queries. Share your index mapping and I'll tell you why you get 88K results (which mght not be the results you expect)